# Laravel api resources and LengthAwarePaginator issue

Tags: laravel, api, eloquent

I'm making an API using Eloquent: API Resources.

This is my article Resource:

```
class Article extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id'       => $this->id,
            'slug'     => $this->slug,
            'name'     => $this->name,
            'comments' => $this->when($this->showComments(), function () {
                $comments = config('eblogger.models.comment')::where([
                    'commentable_type' => get_class($this),
                    'commentable_id'   => $this->id,
                    'parent_id'        => 0,
                ])->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();

                $paginator = makePaginationCollection($comments, route('blog.comments'));

                return CommentResource::collection($paginator);
            }),
        ];
    }
}
```

It's an article with comments.
I want to get pagination with my comments, so i call a custom helper

```
function makePaginationCollection($collection, $path)
{
    $request = request();
    $page = request('page', 1);
    $perPage = config('settings.items_by_pages');

    $paginate = new \Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator(
        $collection->forPage($page, $perPage),
        $collection->count(),
        $perPage,
        $page,
        ['path' => $path]
    );

    return $paginate;
}
```

**Update :** this my resource collection

```
class CommentCollection extends ResourceCollection
{
/**
 * Transform the resource collection into an array.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return array
 */
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'data' => $this->collection,
    ];
}
}
```

but when i inspect the response in the devtools, i see

[image]

I tried with CommentCollection class without success.

Do you have an idea?

Thanks

**My solution**

finally, thanks to @Rwd, i found this solution but I think it is possible to do better:

This is my article Resource:

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        // ...
        'comments' => $this->when($this->showComments(), function() {
            return new CommentCollection(
                $this->comments()
                    ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
                    ->paginate(config('settings.items_by_pages'))
                    ->withPath(route('blog.comments'))
            );
        })
    ];
}
```

And this is my resource collection :

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'data' => $this->collection,
        'links' => $this->resource,
        'meta' => $this->resource
    ];
}
```

Comment: Do you have  a `comments` relationship on the `Article` model (assuming that `Article` is also the name of the model)?

Comment: Yes. if i just return $paginator i can see pagination infos but data array is empty

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question, I meant do you have something like `return $this->morphMany(Comment::class, 'commentable');` in the model (not the resource)?

Comment: yes i have: return  $this->morphMany(Comment::class, 'commentable')->where('parent_id','=', 0);

Comment: Yes it's better because i can return data but i loose pagination links and meta.

Comment: Please can you show the code you have in your `CommentResource` class.

Comment: I updated my question with my CommentResource